# What's the origin of asking interviewees to manually parse a string as an int?

Tags: javascript, string, integer, type-conversion

I'm wondering, what's the origin of asking interviewees to manually parse a string as an int? (without relying on any casting/type-conversion that may be built into the language).  Is this a standard question, suggested from a book or list or something?

Has anybody else here on SO gotten asked this particular question during an interview?  I guess I nailed it when explaining it and scribbling it on the white board, as I have received a tentative job offer :)

Below is my fleshed out implementation in Javascript.  There are some naive facets (e.g. it doesn't take a radix argument) to the following but it demonstrates a (more or less) correct algorithm.

```
function to_i(strValue) { //named so as to not be confused with parseInt
    if (typeof strValue !== 'string' || strValue.length === 0) {
        return Number.NaN;
    }

    var tmpStr = strValue;
    var intValue = 0;
    var mult = 1;

    for (var pos=tmpStr.length-1; pos>=0; pos--) {
        var charCode = tmpStr.charCodeAt(pos);
        if (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) {
            return Number.NaN;
        }

        intValue += mult * Math.abs(48-charCode);
        tmpStr = tmpStr.substr(0, tmpStr.length-1); 
        mult *= 10;
    }

    return intValue;
}
```

Comment: `tmpStr = tmpStr.substr(0, tmpStr.length-1);` seems a little bit unnecessary if you also reverse-iterate over `pos`.

Comment: It also does not seem to handle negative numbers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is trivia of an origin of a programming question, not an actual specific programming question, as defined by the help center. Take a [tour].

Comment: No need for the "take a tour" I've been a member for years, and this question is years old, from when SO was a little free-er and looser.  Anyway maybe a move to programmers/SE is in order.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeJempty, thanks for the clarification; Your post was bumped into [`/realtime`](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) tab earlier, I saw  your interesting yet off-topic and brought it to community attention to be closed. I agree that this post deserves a place on [Programmers.SE], yet one (even moderators) can only migrate a post within 60 days of posting.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Based on the anecdotal evidence from other answers, I will answer this myself, and accept same: this does not seem to be a "canned" interview question.

Comment: I asked for the origin of the interview question.  Nobody knew.  They had lots of opinions about the question, but nobody knew the origin.

Answer (score 13):

I haven't been asked this question, either.

At first glance, it seems like one of those "weed the obviously incompetent idiots out as early as possible to avaid wasting valuable interview time" type of questions.

But if you look at it more closely, there's actually some quite interesting stuff in there. So, if *I* were the one *asking* that question, here's what I would be looking for:

- That question is obviously stupid, because there already *is* a function in the ECMAScript standard library that does exactly that. And I would want the interviewee to *tell* me that the question is stupid, because otherwise they are either a) mindless zombies that stupidly follow braindead orders instead of engaging their brain, or b) they don't actually *know* that that function exists.
- It's also obviously a parsing problem, and it is interesting to see whether the interviewee approaches it as more of a string hacking problem or a formal parsing problem and how much overhead either approach generates. In this particular case, I believe that string hacking is the right approach, but it still leads into a great followup question: "Now do the same thing with a recursive-descent parser". Any programmer should be able to sketch out the recursive-descent parser for this problem within a couple of minutes.
- Last but not least, this is obviously a fold over the characters of the string. Now, I would not necessarily expect a novice programmer to spot this fold on their own right away, but if I hint that there is a fold in there, they should be able to spot it themselves, and rewrite their solution in form of a fold.
- And of course, you can judge all the general qualities that this type of question allows you to: does the interviewee stop and think about the problem or does he start hacking away. Does he start with requirements, documentation, specification, examples, tests, or code. Does he ask for clarification of the corner cases (like what happens with the empty string, what happens with a string that only contains a minus sign and nothing else, what about whitespace, are strings guaranteed to be well-formed integers, is negative zero a well-formed integer). Does he habitually use the strict subset of ES5. Does he write readable code. Does he write `jslint`-friendly code

Here's an example of solving the problem with a fold (which in ECMAScript is called `reduce`):

```
"use strict";

function toInteger(s) {
    return s.split('').reverse().reduce(function (n, c, i) {
        if (c === '-') return -n;
        return n + (c.charCodeAt(0) - 48) * Math.pow(10, i);
    }, 0);
}
```

And this is a simple recursive-descent parser which builds up the value on the fly:

```
"use strict";

function toInteger(s) {
    var input,
        output = 0,
        sign = 1,

        lookahead = function () {
            return input.charAt(0);
        },

        consume = function () {
            var res = input.slice(0, 1);
            input = input.slice(1, input.length);
            return res;
        },

        isDigit = function (c) {
            return /[0-9]/.test(c);
        },

        signParser = function () {
            if (lookahead() === '-') {
                sign *= -1;
                consume();
            }
        },

        digitParser = function () {
            if (!isDigit(lookahead())) return false;
            output *= 10;
            output += (consume().charCodeAt(0) - 48);
            return true;
        },

        numberParser = function () {
            signParser();
            while (digitParser());
        };

    input = s;
    numberParser();
    if (!input.length === 0) return false;
    output *= sign;

    return output;
}
```

As is always the case with this kind of interview questions, nobody would seriously expect the interviewee to just write those functions down on the whiteboard. Especially the recursive-descent parser. But IMHO, anybody *should* be able to sketch out what the function would look like. In particular, one of the beauties of a recursive-descent parser is that it is a very direct transformation of a context-free grammar into a set of parsing functions, and an interviewee should be able to explain roughly how that transformation works, and what kind of parsing functions correspond to what kind of grammar constructs.

---

*phew*, that is a *lot* of stuff that you can get out of such a simple question!

Comment: Note: I wrote both functions first in Ruby, and only decided to translate them into ECMAScript later, because that's what the question mentioned. Also, I don't actually *know* ECMAScript. Therefore, there might be some un-idiomatic code in there. If that's the case, please tell me, so I can fix it. (Or just fix it yourself.)

Comment: There's so much more to programming then grammar parsing, just like there's so much more to architecture than plain masonry. (In fact, I know couple of great architects that don't know jack about masonry...)

Comment: This answer is akin to suggesting a nuclear bomb is needed to kill a fly rather than a fly swatter.  One does not need to demonstrate they can build a car from the ground up in order to drive one.  Even if I had the technical acumen to give such an answer, I would like to think I would have the sense to hold back on completely alienating my potential future managers and co-engineers, until I actually had the job.

Comment: what's a fold anyway - bing gave me this -http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20091/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RVBS_ffold

Comment: It's NOT obviously stupid. It is a simple function and a weeder.  I might give it as a warm up on a new-grad level interview.  However, just because a simple function exists doesn't mean you shouldn't need to be able to derive a simple function.  It's something almost everyone should understand, and roughly no one who is competent should fail to be able to write. 

@George - if you can't figure out how the car works in general, while it's fine to drive one, you shouldn't hold a position BUILDING them.

Comment: @James: figuring out how the car works in general is fine, building one from the ground up is another matter.  What if you can figure out how to build (and eventually fly) a helicopter from a kit?  Is that good enough?  Do you have to understand aerodynamics at a Newtonian (or whoever) level?

Answer (score 2):

They wanted to test your math knowledge, because many "code monkeys" did not receive proper math education.

A number that is expressed in digits $d_1 d_2...d_n$ can be written in this form: $d_1 r^(n - 1) + ... + d_(n - 1) r^1 + d_n$, where r is the radix.

That means, 123 in decimal = $1 * 10^2 + 2 * 10^1 + 3$
while 123 in octal is $1 * 8^2 + 2 * 8^1 + 3$ = 83

```
function to_i(str, rad) {
  // the function to transform an ascii code into a number value
  function dig(c) {
    if (c >= 48 && c <= 57) {
      // 0 - 9: as-is
      return c - 48;
    } else if (c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
      // a - z: a means 10, b means 11 and so on until z
      return 10 + c - 97;
    } else {
      return Number.NaN;
    }
  }

  // validate arguments
  if (str == '' || rad < 2 || rad > 35) return Number.NaN;
  // strip extra characters and lowercase ("$10" -> "10")
  var result = str.toLowerCase().match(/^.*?(-?)([a-z0-9]+).*?$/);
  // break on empty numbers
  if (result == null || !result[2]) return Number.NaN;
  // get sign multiplier
  var sign = (result[1] == '-' ? -1 : 1), val = result[2], num = 0;
  // num = dv_0 * rad ** n + dv1 * rad ** (n - 1) + ... dv_n * rad ** 0
  //  where dv_n = dig(val.charCodeAt(i))
  //  and a ** b = a * ... * a, b times
  // for each digits
  for (var i = val.length - 1, m = 1; i >= 0; i --, m *= rad) {
    // get digit value
    var dv = dig(val.charCodeAt(i));
    // validate digit value (you can't put 5 in binary)
    if (dv >= rad || num == Number.NaN) return Number.NaN;
    // multiply
    num += m * dv;
  }
  // return 
  return num * sign;
}

to_i("ff", 16);
```

This one supports radixes, `a` means 10, `b` means 11 and so on until `z`.
Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of this question either, during interviews in US they always asked me much harder questions. I wish they asked me such a simple question.

Comment: why do you think this Qs was not asked in US?

Comment: @Jack: I was only explaining that when I was in US during the iterviews they asked me harder coding questions. I had specific coding interviews only in US, in Italy they never interviewed me on code they simply trusted my degree. I don't see why they gave -2.

Comment: Maybe its because you a) don't actually answer the question and b) you come off as disparaging